# How to get client info in firebase functions using ipinfo.io

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When a user just joins the app, I want to get their location info using ipinfo.

I tried this but doesn't seem to work

```
// Create User location table
export async function updateLocation(user: any): Promise<any> {
   return await app.get('https://ipinfo.io', (req, res) => {
       console.log(res, req)
    return  db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        'contactInfo': {
            res
        }
    }, { merge: true });
 });
}
```

What would be the way to do this in firebase-functions?

`//app.get('https://ipinfo.io', (req, res)`  The request doesn't seem to be send...

I am using cors and express middleware

Comment: Are you on a paid plan? As the Pricing page explains "The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services." If you want to interact with a service that is outside Google, you must be under the Flame or Blaze plans. See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Am on a blaze plan!